# Echo a PHP Variable multiple times

Tags: php, math, variables, echo

How would one go about echoing a variable multiple times..

A way to understand this question better would be if I said:

```
$foo = '<div>bar</div>';
echo $foo*7;
```

It's probably the most simple thing, but I'm not sure.

And

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-repeat.php

Comment: In virtually all programming languages, the way to repeat code is with a loop. You'll find the syntax for loops in the introductory chapters of that language's manual.

Comment: $foo * 7 is an invalid expression in your case. I think it will give you an error. But if you only have numbers in your $foo, it would actually be fine.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In this simple case, you can use [`str_repeat()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-repeat.php).

```
$foo = '<div>bar</div>';
echo str_repeat($foo, 7);
```

Reference: [PHP string functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php)

For anything more complex, a loop is usually the way to go.

Answer (score 5):

Don't multiply strings. You can either do it manually:

```
echo $variable;
echo $variable;
echo $variable;
echo $variable;
// etc
```

Or in a for loop:

```
for($z=0;$z<10;$z++){
  echo $variable;
}
```

Or str_repeat:

```
echo str_repeat($variable, 10);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for ($i = 0, $i <= 7, $i++) {
    echo $foo;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `str_repeat()`.

```
echo str_repeat($foo, 7);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `for` loop.....................

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php

Comment: This is not a very generous answer.   Could have been a comment.