# Is there any manual method other than "str_repeat" to repeat the string?

Tags: php

I mean if we give 3, b as parameters passed into function, it should return "bbb" by using loops.

I've tried some code, but I do not want to post it because it might look crazy for a well-versed developer. I can provide you links, this question has been asked in an interview, mainly they want it to be computed in C or C++. Since I am a PHP practitioner, I am curious to know it is possible in PHP. Below is the link (ROUND 2: SIMPLE CODING(3 hours))
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/zoho-interview-set-3-campus/

Comment: [PHP For looping a string multiple times in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23105162/2943403)

Comment: [Echo a PHP Variable multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4777988/2943403)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A PHP function to do that would probably look like this:

```
function string_repeat($num, $string)
{
    $result = "";
    for ($x = 0; $x < $num; $x++) {
        $result .= $string;
    }
    return $result;
}
```

So calling `echo string_repeat(3, 'b');` would output:

```
bbb
```

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to keep around a "dummy" string, of sufficient length to be longer than any string you want to generate.  Then, we can use `preg_replace` to replace each character with whatever the input is.  Finally, we can substring that replace string to the desired length.

```
$dummy = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
$length = 3;
$dummy = preg_replace('/./', 'b', $dummy);
$output = substr($dummy, 0, $length);
echo $output;
```

This prints:

```
bbb
```

You could wrap this into a helper function, if you really wanted to do that.  Note that internally the regex engine is most likely doing some looping of its own, so we are not really freeing ourselves from looping, just hiding it from the current context.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen you can take random_bytes with $length param to be sure, you have it long enough